# ActiveRecord #find getting wrong class of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models:  CreditCard and BlacklistItem::CreditCard.  If I search for a BlacklistItem::CreditCard first, I get the expected behaviour:

```
>> BlacklistItem::CreditCard.find(:all).first
=> #<BlacklistItem::CreditCard id: 5, *snip* >
>>
```

If I search for a CreditCard first, when I go to look for BlacklistItem::CreditCard items later I get unexpected behaviour:

```
>> CreditCard.find(:all).first
=> #<CreditCard id: 2, key_id: 4, *snip* >
>> BlacklistItem::CreditCard.find(:all).first
(irb):2: warning: toplevel constant CreditCard referenced by BlacklistItem::CreditCard
=> #<CreditCard id: 2, key_id: 4, *snip* >
>>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is it just impossible to have names with this kind of relationship between them?  I'm going to rename BlacklistItem::CreditCard as a work around, but it really would be the best name for this particular object.

Comment: Can you show us the 2 model classes?  That might help figure out what's going on here.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not comfortable divulging how we store credit cards.  Suffice it to say that we have not overridden #find in any way.

Comment: As an aside, you can call `first` directly e.g: `CreditCard.first`.

Comment: Nor do I want to know how you store credit cards.  I thought the model definition (appropriately sanitized to remove sensitive info) would help provide a solution to you question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Namespaced models in Rails have been buggy for quite a while.  There's a good writeup on the matter [here](http://www.strictlyuntyped.com/2008/08/activerecord-can-haz-namespaces.html).  You might try explicitly specifying the table name to use for blacklisted credit cards in the model via:

```
class BlacklistItem::CreditCard
  set_table_name :blacklist_item_credit_card

  ...

end
```

However, even with this, having a top level CreditCard model and namespaced one, BlacklistItem::CreditCard, you may still run into problems due to Rails' automagic behavior.